# write byte array in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

These are some elements i need to put them in a byte array 16 elements

```
[3A, 60, 43, 2A, 5C, 01, 21, IF, 29, 1E, 0F, 4E, 0C, 13, 28, 25]
```

But i use Uint8List to create byte array but when i add them it gives error

```
  List<Uint8List> key =[3A, 60, 43, 2A, 5C, 01, 21, IF, 29, 1E, 0F, 4E, 0C, 13, 28, 25];

The element type 'int' can't be assigned to the list type 'Uint8List'. (Documentation)
Expected to find ','.
Undefined name 'A'. (Documentation)  Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name.
```

how can i create a byte array using these elements?

Comment: What do you expect the byte representation to be? `3A` looks like a hexadecimal value for a single byte, but then `PW`, `6G`, `8H`, and `UJ` clearly aren't hexadecimal values.  How is `UJ` supposed to be encoded into a byte?

Comment: i need hexadecimal

Comment: You have a bunch of values that aren't valid hexadecimal numbers, so you're going to need to clarify what you expect to do with them.

Comment: please consider them all as a hexadecimal

Comment: so can you tell me how can i make a byte array of hexadecimal in dart?

Comment: Again, that's impossible because things like `UJ` aren't valid hexadecimal numbers.  That's like asking to consider "xyzzy" as a base-10 number.  Is `UJ` actually something you need to write into the byte array, or did you accidentally make up invalid values?

Comment: i have changed the values to hexadecimal now
can you write a small example please

Comment: Hexadecimal integer literals are prefixed with `0x`, so you'd do: `Uint8List key = Uint8List.fromList([0x3A, 0x60, 0x43, 0x2A, 0x5C, 0x01, 0x21, ...])`.  It would fail at `IF`, though, which again is not a valid hexadecimal number.

Answer (score 0):

if they are in hex format you can start them of in a string representation

```dart
final strings = ['3A', '60', '43', '2A']; // List<String>
```

if you want these values transformed to an integer representation you can do:

```dart
final integers = strings.map((s) => int.parse(s, radix: 16)).toList(); //List<Int>
```